# This IP was already used for a trial - spaming admin email

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, spam-prevention, denial-of-service

I use amazon lightsail and I get a lot of generated emails saying:
"The IP .... was already used for a trial license on 2019-03-13" 
Where the IP changes to different IPs. The emails are from my cron daemon. What do these emails mean and what I do I need to do about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have a license, this might be solved with:

```
sudo apt-get remove kernelcare
```

Comment: What I am going to do resolve this issue now that I know it's kernelcare, i'm going to buy kernelcare, so I don't have to worry about my servers. Thanks for letting me know where to look though!